# SQL query to calculate days difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below:

```
ID    Level    Date      Days difference

123    B       1/6/2014      ------
123    A       5/16/2014     ------ 
123    B       9/21/2014     ------
123    B       12/19/2014    ------
123    B       3/17/2015     305
123    A       4/5/2015      ------
123    A       8/11/2015     ------ 
123    B       10/12/2015    62
```

Total Days Difference             367

I need a SQL query to get total days difference as above. It should be last date of B before A subtract date of closest A.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Or maybe it is as simple using SUM??

Comment: What you mean by "*It should be last date of B before A*"

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement together with lag/lead to get the correct results:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
    ([ID] int, [Level] varchar(1), [Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #tmp
    ([ID], [Level], [Date])
VALUES
    (123, 'B', '2014-01-06 02:00:00'),
    (123, 'A', '2014-05-16 03:00:00'),
    (123, 'B', '2014-09-21 03:00:00'),
    (123, 'B', '2014-12-19 02:00:00'),
    (123, 'B', '2015-03-17 02:00:00'),
    (123, 'A', '2015-04-05 03:00:00'),
    (123, 'A', '2015-08-11 03:00:00'),
    (123, 'B', '2015-10-12 03:00:00')
;

select *,
datediff(day, case when isnull(lead(Level) over (order by Date asc),'A') = 'A' and Level = 'B' then max(ADate) over (order by Date asc) else NULL end, [Date]) as Diff
from (
  select *, 
    case when lag(Level) over (order by Date desc) = 'B' and Level = 'A' then [Date] else NULL end as ADate
  from #tmp
) X
```

The inner select will determine A-rows from where the date is taken, and the outer query will determine the B-rows where the value is to be calculated + calculate it.

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/449398).